# twilio Rest api call making not working

Tags: php, twilio

I am really frustrated as I can't figure out why my [Twilio callStatus](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request#request-parameters-call-status) for the REST api is not working :S...Any ideas?

It makes a call at stackoverflow.php but when it hits the yournextnumber.php it doesn't execute the if statements because most likely there is no value in the callStatus any idea why the status is not being sent?

stackoverflow.php

```
<?php
// Include the Twilio PHP library
require 'Services/Twilio.php';

// Twilio REST API version
$version = "2010-04-01";

// Set our Account SID and AuthToken
$sid = '....';
$token = '....';


// A phone number you have previously validated with Twilio
$phonenumber = '....';

// Instantiate a new Twilio Rest Client
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token, $version);
try {
  // Initiate a new outbound call
  $call = $client->account->calls->create(
    $phonenumber, // The number of the phone initiating the call
    '....', // The number of the phone receiving call
    'http://demo.twilio.com/welcome/voice/',
    array('Timeout'=>5,
          'IfMachine'=>'hangup',
          'StatusCallback'=>'http://example.com/twilio-twilio-php-28c214f/yourNextNumberHandler.php'));

  echo 'Started call: ' . $call->sid;
  echo 'The status of the call is '.$call->status;
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

yourNextNumber.php

```
  <?php
// Include the Twilio PHP library
    require 'Services/Twilio.php';

    // Twilio REST API version
    $version = "2010-04-01";
    print_r()//error_log() $_REQUEST
    // Set our Account SID and AuthToken
    $sid = '....';
    $token = '....';


// A phone number you have previously validated with Twilio
    $phonenumber = '....';

// Instantiate a new Twilio Rest Client
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token, $version);


if ($_REQUEST['CallStatus']=='completed')
{

try {
// Initiate a new outbound call
$call = $client->account->calls->create(
$phonenumber, // The number of the phone initiating the call
'..', // The number of the phone receiving call
'http://demo.twilio.com/welcome/voice/',
array('Timeout'=>5)
);

}
catch (Exception $e) {
echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

}   



if ($_REQUEST['CallStatus']=='no-answer')
{

try {
// Initiate a new outbound call
$call = $client->account->calls->create(
$phonenumber, // The number of the phone initiating the call
'...', // The number of the phone receiving call
'http://demo.twilio.com/welcome/voice/',
array('Timeout'=>5)
);

}
catch (Exception $e) {
echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
}


if ($_REQUEST['CallStatus']=='ringing')
{

try {
// Initiate a new outbound call
$call = $client->account->calls->create(
$phonenumber, // The number of the phone initiating the call
'....', // The number of the phone receiving call
'http://demo.twilio.com/welcome/voice/',
array('Timeout'=>5)
);

}
catch (Exception $e) {
echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
}


if ($_REQUEST['CallStatus']=='busy')
{

try {
// Initiate a new outbound call
$call = $client->account->calls->create(
$phonenumber, // The number of the phone initiating the call
'...', // The number of the phone receiving call
'http://demo.twilio.com/welcome/voice/',
array('Timeout'=>5)
);

}
catch (Exception $e) {
echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
}

if ($_REQUEST['CallStatus']=='queued')
{

try {
// Initiate a new outbound call
$call = $client->account->calls->create(
$phonenumber, // The number of the phone initiating the call
'....', // The number of the phone receiving call
'http://demo.twilio.com/welcome/voice/',
array('Timeout'=>5)
);

}
catch (Exception $e) {
echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
}

    ?>
```

Comment: 'because most likely there is no value' - you should at least `print_r()`/`error_log()` `$_REQUEST` so you know if it has a value.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked your PHP error log? You need a `catch` for each of those `try` blocks.

Comment: the issue is that the file for logs is hidden and I dont have access to it...So I can do anything for that.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using if statements for the CallStatus processing, convert it to a switch statement. That way you can set a default case that gets performed regardless of the status. Then you could easily log (or notify someone) when you find an unexpected CallStatus.